# regex expression to get text before string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have string text in c# which I am trying to get all the words before my expresssion `eachDELETEDDELETED` and I want to turn those into a list or array. Can someone help with the regex portion.

text sample: 
`word word word word word word 20 word-16S eachDELETEDDELETEDword word word word word word 20 word-16z1 (size 26), eachDELETEDDELETED`

```
Regex ry = new Regex(@"eachDELETEDDELETED");
MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(extracted, ry.ToString());
var list = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();

foreach (string s in list)
{
    richTextBox2.Text += s + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you a single word (many time in a text) before "eachDELETEDDELETED" or a group of word before "eachDELETEDDELETED"

Comment: group of words then "eachDELETEDDELETED"  and then group of words then "eachDELETEDDELETED"..etc

Comment: Can you provide us a text sample so I can test on my side?

Comment: i tried this regex also and it didnt work   Regex ry = new Regex(@"^.*(?=(\eachDELETEDDELETED))");

Comment: word word word word word word 20 word-16S eachDELETEDDELETEDword word word word word word 20 word-16S eachDELETEDDELETED

Comment: You can work with capture groups and do something like https://regex101.com/r/xP9vQ5/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Regex.Split:

```
string example = "word word word word word word 20 word-16S eachDELETEDDELETEDword word word word word word 20 word-16S eachDELETEDDELETED";
string[] parts = Regex.Split(example, "eachDELETEDDELETED");
foreach(string part in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(part);
}
```

Will output:

```
word word word word word word 20 word-16S 
word word word word word word 20 word-16S
```

Comment: i didn't know about the the spit method, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, this can also be done with a lookahead and the `\G` anchor:

```
^|\G(?:([-\w]+)\s*)(?!(?:eachDELETEDDELETED))
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eR1uW6/1).